# Change a list of presented view controllers in swift like

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

My app has complex transition sequence:

1. A presents modal B
2. B presents modal C
3. A presents D (behind B)
4. C is dismissed to D

The problem is how to insert D. In case of push-pop animations navigationController has `viewControllers` property which I can change as I wish. But what to do in case of modal view controllers?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper 1)I already have a code which already has presented view controller and successfully pushes view controller. The problem is with transitions only. 2)read the question carefully - I can change `viewControllers` as I wish and then call push/pop. And it will work. The problem is with modal presentation by itself

Answer (score 0):

You could put D controller's view inside a view on controller A - and you manage it like a normal view - hide / show with animation.

You could have something like this in controller A:

```
let dController = DController()
if let dView = dController.view {
   self.view.addSubview(dView)
}
```

Comment: no suitable for my situation, because "A presents D" also means D may be dismissed to A. Currently D is pushed (instead of presenting) but it makes troubles with dismissing D animation

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

1. A presents modal NC (`UINavigationController` with hidden navigation bar) with B as rootViewController
2. NC presents modal C
3. NC rootViewController is replaced with D
4. C is dismissed to NC

In other words I didn't find how to replace presenting/presented view controllers but I can build in them into navigation controllers. It is better than built in views and adding child view controllers because you can still use present/dismiss without of additional difficulties.

It seems `UITabBarController` may work too for this purpose.